# Magento add field dependency in admin form using a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

In an custom admin form,  I have added a custom tab and some custom fields to it. here I need to add field dependency for the fields as described below.

**if the field zipbasedprice_isrange is set to yes, then I need to show other two fields & if it is set to no, then only one field should be shown.
How can I implement this using below form?

Field dependencies should be between zipbasedprice_isrange, zipbasedprice_zip, zipbasedprice_zip_from_zip & zipbasedprice_zip_to_zip.**

I tried default field dependencies, but it did not work. Help me, how to implement this using a javascript function?

```
  $isRange = $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_isrange', 'select', array(
    'name' => 'zipbasedprice_isrange',
    'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Is Range?'),
    'values' => array(
        array(
            'value' => false,
            'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('No'),
        ),
        array(
            'value' => true,
            'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Yes'),
        )
    ),
   'value' => false,
   'onchange' => 'onIsZipRangeChange()',
   'required' => false,
```

'style' => 'width:275px'
      ));

```
$fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_zip', 'text', array(
    'name' => 'zipbasedprice_zip',
    'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Zip Code'),
    'class' => 'input',
    'required' => true,
'style' => 'width:268px',
    'value' => '*',
    'maxlength' => 6,
 ));


 $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_zip_from_zip', 'text', array(
    'name' => 'zipbasedprice_zip_from_zip',
    'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Zip Code From'),
    'class' => 'input',
    'required' => true,
'style' => 'width:268px',
    'value' => '*',
    'maxlength' => 6,
 ));

  $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_zip_to_zip', 'text', array(
    'name' => 'zipbasedprice_zip_to_zip',
    'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Zip Code To'),
    'class' => 'input',
    'required' => true,
'style' => 'width:268px',
    'value' => '*',
    'maxlength' => 6,
 ));
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried.?

Comment: I tired the following code;
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
                ->addFieldMap('zip_is_range', 'zip_is_range')
                ->addFieldMap('tax_postcode', 'tax_postcode')
                ->addFieldMap('zip_from', 'zip_from')
                ->addFieldMap('zip_to', 'zip_to')
                ->addFieldDependence('zip_from', 'zip_is_range', '1')
                ->addFieldDependence('zip_to', 'zip_is_range', '1')
                ->addFieldDependence('tax_postcode', 'zip_is_range', '0')
        );

Comment: Based on your code, which field you need to show and which one to hide ?

Comment: On select of range 'yes', It should show two fields zip from and zip to.  whereas in case of no selection and range 'no', it should show zip code field.

Answer (score 0):

In file js/mage/adminhtml/form.js you will find a Javascript class with the name FormElementDependenceController.

You will also find a explanation how to structure the dependencies in the class constructor.

You could try this:

```
new FormElementDependenceController(
['zipbasedprice_zip','zipbasedprice_zip_from_zip','zipbasedprice_zip_to_zip'],
{'zipbasedprice_isrange':1}
);
```